# How does _netdev mount option in /etc/fstab work?

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, automounting, sshfs

I'd like to know what is the exact mechanism (implementation) used to defer mounting until after network interface is up when one uses `_netdev` option in `/etc/fstab`?
Does `systemd` alter this behavior?
Also, what does `delay_connect` option to sshfs provide what `_netdev` does not?

From `mount` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

> **`_netdev`**
>                 The filesystem resides on a device that requires network
>                 access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount
>                 these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the
>                 system).

From `sshfs` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs):

> **`-o delay_connect`**
>   delay connection to server

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From `man systemd.mount` for version 231 of systemd:

> Mount units referring to local and network file systems are
>   distinguished by their file
>          system type specification. In some cases this is not sufficient (for example network block device based mounts, such as
>          iSCSI), in which case **_netdev** may be added to the mount option string of the unit, which forces systemd to consider the mount
>          unit a network mount.

Comment: Awsome! No idea why this answer hasn't been up-voted yet.

Comment: it doesn't work in debian stretch.

Comment: This doesn't explain why an fstab definition without `_netdev` fails not only at boot but also later at run time (with `mount -a`), but succeeds when this flag is added.

Comment: Does this work on Mac?

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto - Noticed your comment. https://wiki.debian.org/fstab < it is not mentioned once in the wiki either as an option. As of Bookworm it doesn't seem to be observed at all, while I have heard using `x-systemd.automount` as an option "fixes" this, but haven't tested. Enabling the systemd-networkd-wait-online.service worked for me as a fix too, but it adds boot delay.

Answer (score 37):

## SysV Init

The `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh` init script mounts local filesystems only:

```
mount -a -t nonfs,nfs4,smbfs,cifs,ncp,ncpfs,coda,ocfs2,gfs,gfs2,ceph -O no_netdev
```

Other filesystems are mounted by separate init scripts, like for example `/etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh`, which declare (via LSB headers) their dependency on `$network`. Thus these get scheduled later, after the network is brought up, while `mountall.sh` can run much earlier.

## systemd

Local mount units are pulled in by `local-fs.target`, remote ones by `remote-fs.target`. `systemd-fstab-generator` scans `/etc/fstab`, generates mount units and assigns these to the above targets based on conditions similar to the above.

## delay_connect

This option means that sshfs will not initiate the SSH connection to the remote server at mount time, but will only do so on the first filesystem operation actually requiring it. This delays error reporting, but might be a useful workaround in some cases, for example if your init system hasn't got enough information to order the mount operation correctly. "The network" being "up" is a rather [loose term](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/), and even though one can add arbitrary [extra dependencies](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) to mount units that doesn't help if the trigger event is not part of the bootup transaction (in systemd parlance).

Comment: So, you are saying that `_netdev` is not meant to be an argument passed to the process which performs mount (and which is specific to the type of mount like `ext4/btrfs/cifs/fuse`) but is meant to be read by other processes/scripts which based upon this flag decide when during the boot process these mounts should be executed. Yes? If so then I suspect this is the reason why this argument starts with underscore so that to differentiate it from other *formal* arguments.

Comment: Yes. If you pass the `_netdev` option to the `mount` command, it will be visible in `/proc/mounts` but have no other effect.

Comment: Bonus question; is this documented somewhere?

Comment: The [mount](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mount&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en) manual contains: "FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS — Some of these options are only useful when they appear in the `/etc/fstab` file." Well, `_netdev` (documented somewhat later) is a fine example for this.

Comment: *The _netdev option is ignored in mount(8) by default. The options is used by initscripts only.* – https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=607309#c4

Answer (score 2):

`Upstart/Udev`

For `upstart` and/or `udev` based systems this is slightly different.

It seems `udev` will still try to mount the NFS filesystems and `netfs` is a safety net for when that fails.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. either way, this answer is only relevant for some recent legacy systems (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, RHEL6).