# Idle timeout for NFS share mounted with systemd automount

Tags: debian, systemd, nfs, fstab, autofs

## What I want to do?

I want to configure my [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) so that my [NFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS) share was:

- mounted automatically when accessed (auto-mount on-demand),
- unmounted automatically after specified idle timeout ([x-systemd.idle-timeout](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.idle-timeout=)).

AFAIK, I can achieve this behavior using [AutoFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs) or [systemd automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html). I prefer [`systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) because I don't want to install additional packages unless needed.

## What's my problem?

This is excerpt from my `/etc/fstab` (I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Remote_filesystem)):

```
192.168.1.14:/home/someuser/somedir /mnt/someuser_share nfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=30,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min,_netdev 0 0
```

Note that in the above line there is:

```
x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min
```

but it *doesn't work*. After waiting 1 minute without using `/mnt/someuser_share` it is still mounted.

*Why it doesn't work as expected?*

## Additional info

Note that after system bootup my share is not mounted as expected. After I type eg. `ls /mnt/someuser_share` it's mounted (if `192.168.1.14` is online). After next 1 minute I would expect that my share will be unmounted, but it isn't.

I'm using [Debian Stretch (9.6)](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch), ie. current [Debian Stable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStable). [`systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) version: 232.

As a side note: I'm aware that [`systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) reads [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) and creates [unit files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), specifically [automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) and [mount unit files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) that can be listed using [`systemctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Basic_systemctl_usage) command and viewed using [`systemctl cat name-of-the-unit-file`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units#unit-management).

---

## Update #1

Removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) mount option from `/etc/fstab` worked (as suggested by *[@D'Arcy Nader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/172889/darcy-nader)* in [the comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491367/idle-timeout-for-nfs-share-mounted-with-systemd-automount#comment901622_491367)), but I don't understand why it actually helped. [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) is intended to be used with the remote shares because it forces [`systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) to consider the mount unit a network mount. So why it breaks things up?

Content of `mnt-someuser_share.automount` before and after removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) mount option remains the same:

```
root@someuser:~$ systemctl cat mnt-someuser_share.automount
# /run/systemd/generator/mnt-someuser_share.automount
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=remote-fs.target

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/someuser_share
TimeoutIdleSec=1min
```

as opposed to content of `mnt-someuser_share.mount` which differs. Before removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115):

```
root@parents-desktop:~$ systemctl cat mnt-someuser_share.mount
# /run/systemd/generator/mnt-someuser_share.mount
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

[Mount]
What=192.168.1.14:/home/someuser/somedir
Where=/mnt/someuser_share
Type=nfs
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min,_netdev
```

After removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) last line changes – instead of:

```
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min,_netdev
```

there is:

```
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min
```

---

## Update #2

After experimenting with [NFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS) shares and mount options, I noticed that my `/mnt/someuser_share` share is automatically mounted immediately after system bootup and it's not unmounted after 1 minute (again), even though I don't have [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) option in my [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab). After I removed all the files from `/mnt/someuser_share` it worked again.

To make things even more confusing, after I made it work again, I appended [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) option back to [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) and it still works fine, so there must be some misunderstanding what does it actually mean that the remote share is *idle for 1 minute*.

Comment: can you specify both which version of systemd and distribution are you using ?

Comment: I updated my post ([Debian Stable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStable), ie. Debian Stretch [9.6] + [`systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) ver. 232).

Comment: have you tried without _netdev and using seconds insted of minutes for x-systemd.idle-timeout=  ?
i would .

Comment: Wow! @D'ArcyNader: honestly, I was quite skeptical about your suggestion, but *it actually worked*! It turned out that after removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) option, my share is automatically unmounted after specified time (I didn't need to replace `1min` with `60`). Do you know why is that? You can post the answer with the explanation, so that I can accept it. :-)

Comment: I turned out that removing [`_netdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331688/28115) didn't help (I misinterpreted it), but removing the files from the remote share did help. See update in my post.

Comment: quoting from man systemd.mount :"Mount units referring to local and network file systems are distinguished by their file system type specification. In some cases this is not sufficient (for example network block device based mounts, such as iSCSI), in which case _netdev may be added to the mount option string of the unit, which forces systemd to consider the mount unit a network mount."

Comment: you can check if there are files open with `lsof` when it doesn't unmount automatically. if there is a file open the nfs is not considered idle by the system.

Comment: I'm still experimenting and I'm totally confused because now I have empty `/mnt/someuser_share` and it is not unmounted automatically (again). [`lsof | grep -i mnt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) returns nothing. I'm lost. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87648/discussion-between-darcy-nader-and-patryk-beza).