# Issue with correct syntax of /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

The next command works:

`sudo mount -t nfs4 10.10.1.10:/Data /mnt/data`

How do I reformat this to `/etc/fstab` to add in? I can't get it mounting on boot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following string:

`10.10.1.10:/Data    /mnt/data    nfs    vers=4,_netdev    0    0`

Mount options description:

`vers=4` - uses version 4 of NFS protocol.

`_netdev` - mount after network initializing.

Comment: `_netdev` is largely superfluous when the filesystem type is `nfs`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169697/5132

Comment: @JdeBP Agree. But in one system, that was based on Debian Jessi I have a problem with mounting nfs during boot without `_netdev` option. In other (most recent) systems all seems to be ok. So, for the most predictable and clarify behavior I mentioned `_netdev` option.